# strings in the subscript in c

Tags: c

What is the meaning of the below code? I thought that it is compilation error. But no compilation error occurs.

```
int main() 
{ 
    const int a=1; 
    printf("%c", ++a["Gyantonic"]); 
}
```

Output in Linux a is segmentation fault. It gives a compilation error if `a[1]` is given in place of `++a["Gyantonic"]`.

How does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 ++a["Gyantonic"]
```

is equivalent to:

```
++(a["Gyantonic"])
```

which is equivalent to

```
++("Gyantonic"[a])
```

equivalent to

```
++("Gyantonic"[1])
```

`"Gyantonic"[1]` yields `'y'` and the `++` increments the `'y'` stored in the string literal and yields the result. But `"Gyantonic"` is a string literal and string literals cannot be modified. This is why you get the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the expression `x[y]` is exactly equal to `*(x+y)`.  Since addition is commutative, that means you can also write it as `y[x]`, which is `*(y+x)`, the same thing.

Comment: In the question above if a[1] is given in place of a["guantonic"] it gives compilation error

Comment: Yes, because `a[1]` is equivalent to `*(a+1)`, or `*2`, which doesn't make any sense, 2 is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
++a["Gyantonic"]
```

means that you are trying to increment the a-th (hence, the 1-st, which is not the first but the *second*, C strings beginning at 0) character of "Gyantonic".

And since "Gyantonic" is a read only constant string, none of its character may be incremented, and you get a segmentation fault.

In gcc with warnings enabled you get:

```
 warning: increment of read-only location ‘"Gyantonic"[a]’ [enabled by default]
```

The intended output is apparently "z" (the "y" in Gyantonic incremented by 1). To do this you should write:

```
    char string[] = "Gyantonic";
    const int a=1;
    printf("%c", ++a[string]);
```

Note that this is not the same as writing

```
    char *string = "Gyantonic";
```

The first version creates an array and initializes (COPIES) in this writeable array the existing, readonly string "Gyantonic". The second version creates a *pointer*, a *label* to the existing, readonly string "Gyantonic".

Writing to the writeable copy string[] is allowed; writing to the readonly pointed by *string will segfault.